# Transaction time out workaround for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, timeout

AFAIK, PostgreSQL 8.3 does not support transaction time out.  I've read about supporting this feature in the future and there's some discussion about it.  However, for specific reasons, I need a solution for this problem.  So what I did is a script that runs periodically:

1) Based on locks and activity, query in order to retrieve processID of the transactions that is taking too long, and keeping the oldest (*trxTimeOut.sql*):

```
SELECT procpid
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT age(now(), query_start) AS age, procpid
    FROM pg_stat_activity, pg_locks
    WHERE pg_locks.pid = pg_stat_activity.procpid
) AS foo
WHERE age > '30 seconds'
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 1
```

2) Based on this query, kill the corresponding process (*trxTimeOut.sh*):

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -t -d test_database -f trxTimeOut.sql | xargs kill
```

Although I've tested it and seems to work, I'd like to know if it's an acceptable approach or should I consider a different one?

Comment: Is an upgrade to at least version 8.4 an option? If so, you can use pg_terminate_backend() to kill open connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I can't take that upgrade for granted (doesn't depend on me).  Anyway, pg_terminate_backend() would only be a better way to end the connection than the kill command, right?  I mean, the query + kill (or terminate) solution is relatively acceptable?

Answer (score 17):

PostgreSQL provides [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html) since version 9.6, to automatically terminate transactions that are idle for too long.

It's also possible to set a limit on how long a command can take, through `statement_timeout`, independently on the duration of the transaction it's in, or why it's stuck (busy query or waiting for a lock).

To auto-abort transactions that are stuck specifically waiting for a lock, see `lock_timeout`.

These settings can be set at the SQL level with commands like `SET` shown below, or can be set as defaults to a database with `ALTER DATABASE`, or to a user with `ALTER USER`, or to the entire instance through `postgresql.conf`.

```
SET statement_timeout=10000;   -- time out after 10 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is a little more complex. If a client app. hangs for some reason (ie related with a Java Swing event, but not related with a statement that takes too long), this could eventually block other clients since the first client has some locks granted (in the not commited/rollbacked transaction) that the second one is waiting to access.  The script kills the first transaction because is taking too long, no matter the source of the problem (thus allowing the second client to continue). statement_timeout will only abort the transaction of the second client (because of the locks)

Comment: `statement_timeout` doesn't address "idle in transaction" state, which can still prevent log replay. There are some very concrete cases where this answer isn't good enough.

Comment: Version 9.6x has an `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` property now in addition to `statement_timeout`.

Comment: @gregtzar: I've rewritten the answer that was indeed as obsolete as PG 8.3. Thanks for the heads up!